# How to create an object list that contain n string properties and one data object but the object type with its properties can change dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to load the property "Data" dynamically depend on the object type. I don't want to do something like this:

```
        List<BaseBoxDTO> listBoxes = new List<BaseBoxDTO>();
        BaseBoxDTO box = new BaseBoxDTO();
        box.Title = "Title1";
        box.Status = "Status1";
        GeneralInfoBoxDTO GI = new GeneralInfoBoxDTO
        {
            value1 = "string1",
            value2 = "string2"
        };
        box.Data = GI;
        listBoxes.Add(box);

        BaseBoxDTO box2 = new BaseBoxDTO();
        box2.Title = "Title2";
        box2.Status = "Status2";

        TrainingBoxDTO traini = new TrainingBoxDTO
        {
            valorproperty1 = "string1",
            valorproperty2 = "string2"
        };
        box2.Data = traini;
        listBoxes.Add(box2);
```

I think there should be a better way maybe using something recursive. I have the following structure

```
public class BaseBox
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }

 public class ChildBox: BaseBox
    {
        public string value1 { get; set; }
        public string value2 { get; set; }
    }

 public class ChildBox2: BaseBox
    {
        public string valueproperty { get; set; }
        public string valueproperty2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I've read this question 3 times and I'm still not really sure what it is about

Comment: You can make BaseBoxDTO class a generic class

Comment: this is my expected result [
 {
  "title": "title1",
        
     "status": "status1",
        
     "data": {
"value1": "string1",
            
       "value2": "string2"
 
      }
    
  },
    
  {
 "title": "title2",
        
    "status": "status2",
        
    "data": {
"valueproperty1": "string1",
 
             "valueproperty2": "string2"
        
            }
    
  }

]